# The Document has moved error

Tags: java, jquery, httpclient, httpwebresponse

After reading various post from stackoverflow and some help from other guys I did authentication in my code and also trying to avoid the redirect that was occuring previously as I am new to all these things. I started getting the same error back of 302 Found, document has moved.

I am trying to make a ajax call to other domain locally from my computer by writing some proxy code in jsp. And this is my jQuery AJAX code that is calling proxy.jsp page.

```
var search_agile_metadata = 'https://doc.xyz.com/rest-services/services/get?id=';

var on_show_info = function() {
var outOfDomainCall = search_agile_metadata + current_doc.id;//An XML document

request_meta_info = $.ajax({
url: "proxy.jsp?url=" + outOfDomainCall,
                type: 'GET',
                success: on_get_metadata,
                error: on_get_metadata_error

        });
```

And my proxy.jsp file is:-

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient,
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet,
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient,
org.apache.http.HttpResponse
,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,
java.net.HttpURLConnection,
java.net.URL,
java.util.Collection,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,
org.w3c.dom.*,
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,
java.net.*,
java.io.*,
org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext,
org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams,
org.apache.http.params.HttpParams,
org.apache.http.Header,
org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
String a_Url = request.getParameter( "url" ) ;

URL url = new URL (a_Url);
String encoding = new String(
         org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
            (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("test:test"))
          );


HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in   = 
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   out.println(line);
}

%>

<%
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
%>
```

And when I get the response back from the server. I get this error. Any idea why I am getting this error back..

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://login.xyz.com/siteminder/cert/13890/smgetcred.scc?TYPE=16777217&amp;REALM=-SM-amp;SMAUTHREASON=0&amp;METHOD=GET&amp;SMAGENTNAME=-SM-3FfhzbcpbcT6grIIICnrPzvFIbogCZlcnVHG8&amp;TARGET</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.58 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.28 Server at doc.xyz.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: `HTTP 401` means "Unauthorized", as you probably know, and the url you are trying to reach seems a bit complicated - partly because it uses the https protocol and partly because of the "nocert" thing, which I don't know what it is. Have you tried a simpler URL, such as "http://www.gnu.org/" or something?

Comment: @André Laszlo, for the simpler url it is working.. I tried that with this xml file `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml`

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you tried another https url? Have you tried the problematic url in a browser?

Comment: @André Laszlo, which url are you talking about.

Comment: The actual url that you try to reach, with ID appended and all.

Comment: So you don't need a developer key or anything? I can't find any documentation for the web service you're using. I agree with Bob below though, there's nothing wrong with your code, you just need to add some authentication to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is HTTPS that is messing you up so much, but the 401 Unauthorized is the key.  Check what the protocol says:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2 .  Your request somehow needs to account for an Authorization header.  I've done this in the past with the HttpClient library:  http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html

Comment: thanks for replying.. So that means I have to use http client library in my JSP and how can I use this library in my above JSP. Any example will be appreciated..

Comment: It doesn't mean that you have to use HttpClient.  What you have to do is provide an Authentication header in your request.  I'm not sure how you do that with plain-jane URL so I recommend HttpClient as I've found it a pretty convenient way to do that.  Just download the HttpClient library and drive through the examples.  Its not too difficult.  Here's a link to their example for Basic authentication:  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup

Comment: Oh, yeah, to import into a JSP you just put the import directives at the top of the JSP like. <%@ page import "org.apache.commons.httpclient.*,org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope,org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;" %> and put the JARs themselves in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I have updated the questions.. And I did the same way as told by you and I started getting back the same error..